# parity bit and error detection

Tags: c, architecture, assembly, character-encoding

I have faced that in my computer architecture course at university. 
I can't understand the parity bit; Why it has two kinds of even and odd.

Can anyone give me clear explain about parity codes?

Comment: Have you looked up Wikipedia?

Comment: possible duplicate of http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parity_bit

Comment: yeah , I Can't find my understanding.

Comment: What do you mean by "two kinds of even and odd"?

Comment: @Mat  Is it a confirmation between sender and receiver that the PF=1/0? Or the receiver should find the PF by itself?

Comment: Read that Wikipedia article. Sender calculates the parity and sends it. Receiver re-calculates parity and verifies that it matches what was sent.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A 'parity bit' is a method of error checking. Imagine that you need to send 8 bits over a connection and determine whether they got through right. You could try sending it twice, that way if there is an error, the receiver will know because the two messages differ. However, this requires two times the bandwidth, which is too much. So often every byte (8 bits) will also have a parity bit. You count up the number of ones in the byte. If it is odd, the parity bit is one. If it is even, the parity bit is zero. That way if there is any single error the receiver will know and only one eighth the extra bandwidth is needed. Examples:

```
Data: 01001001  3 ones, parity bit 1
Data: 00110101  4 ones, parity bit 0
```

If receiver gets `00111101` and parity bit `0`, it will know that there is some corruption.

Of course if there are two errors in the same byte there will be no way to detect this - example if original is `00000001` and received is `00000010` - but this is considered to be rare enough to not worry for most applications.

Answer (score 2):

The first sentence of the [Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parity_bit) is clear enough, and so is the second paragraph... But ohwell.

Given a word of n bits, with n-1 bits to check parity on and 1 bit of parity, the parity bit will be set to:

- 1 if the number of bits set to 1 is odd, 0 otherwise (even parity);
- 0 if the number of bits set to 1 is even, 1 otherwise (odd parity).

Example: `1101011x` where `x` is the parity bit. There are 5 bits set to 1, therefore an odd number: `x` will be set to 1 (even parity) or 0 (odd parity).