# Checksum. Check if the word didn't get distored

Tags: checksum, crc

I have the following 8-bit word with the checksum added (checksum is the last one)

```
1 1 0 1 1 1 0 1 **1**
```

I need to check if the word got distorted.

I've checked the crc algorithm on wikipedia and I saw that I need a divisor to divide the word with the checksum added. The problem is that I don't know how to find out what is the divisor and how to get one.

Comment: What are the stars in the list of bits? Are these placeholders so you actually have a checksum of 5 bits or are these the result of trying to use "bold" inside a code segment?

Comment: Yes, this is a result of bold inside a code segment, I wanted to indicate the CRC added to the word

Comment: Do you mean "checksum" or "crc"? They are different things. You mention "crc" but then you mention "checksum" as well. It looks like it is just a 1-bit checksum.

Comment: Yes I mean the 1-bit checksum

Comment: Does this answer your question? [parity bit and error detection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8694876/parity-bit-and-error-detection)